# Is this a bash-specific method of calling a script: VARIABLE=value bash somescript

Tags: bash, shell-script, bash-scripting

I have worked all my life in HPUX/ksh shell, so bash these days seems to be throwing new ways of doing many things (many of which don't seem to be POSIX compliant - for example 'mkdir -p /root/{abc,def,ghi,jkl}' - apparently this is a coding guideline best-practice in bash / OpenStack - but that's a different rant altogether).

Anyways, I have been seeing this sort of script execution in multiple places in OpenStack code:

```
ENABLE_VCENTER=true bash /root/stack_install.sh
```

Can someone explain how this works - I know that the shell will set the variable and then invoke the shell script (which is the explanation the classic nooB mistake for why variable assignment shouldn't be with spaces - eg. HELLO= world). But what exactly happens internally?

Also, why doesn't it seem to work for me when I try this command:

```
HELLO=world echo $HELLO
```

I get the following output from the shell:

```
[ ubuntuOne : /home/bumblebee ]
> HELLO=world echo $HELLO


[ ubuntuOne : /home/bumblebee ]
>
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 2):

```
HELLO=world echo $HELLO
```

In the above, `bash` does parameter expansion before the statement is executed.  That means that `$HELLO` is replaced with nothing (or whatever the current value of HELLO is) before the statement is executed (which would include setting HELLO to `world`).

Observe:

```
$ HELLO=world bash -c 'echo $HELLO'
world
```

Notice that `echo $HELLO` is inside single quotes.  Single quotes prevent parameter expansion.  That means that HELLO is not evaluated until the `bash` subshell starts up and sees it as an argument.  By that time, HELLO will have been set equal to `world`.

By contrast, consider this line in which the single quotes have been replaced with double quotes:

```
$ HELLO=world bash -c "echo $HELLO"
```

Here nothing prints because double-quotes do not suppress parameter expansion.  Thus, the `bash` command is given two arguments `-c` and `echo`.  Hence, nothing prints.

#### All the gory details

`man bash` explains, in detail, what happens when commands such as the above are processed:

> When a simple command is executed,  the  shell  performs  the
>          following  expansions,  assignments,  and  redirections, from
>          left to right.
>
> ```
>    1.     The words that  the  parser  has  marked  as  variable
>           assignments  (those  preceding  the  command name) and
>           redirections are saved for later processing.
>
>    2.     The words that are not variable assignments  or  redi‐
>           rections  are  expanded.   If  any  words remain after
>           expansion, the first word is taken to be the  name  of
>           the command and the remaining words are the arguments.
>
>    3.     Redirections  are  performed  as described above under
>           REDIRECTION.
>
>    4.     The text after  the  =  in  each  variable  assignment
>           undergoes  tilde  expansion, parameter expansion, com‐
>           mand substitution,  arithmetic  expansion,  and  quote
>           removal before being assigned to the variable.
> ```

Consider again the command:

```
HELLO=world echo $HELLO
```

The argument to `echo` undergoes parameter expansion in step 2 while `bash` does not even begin to assign the new value to HELLO until step 4.

Comment: Aah ok - makes sense now. Thanks. So, I guess, this is a bash-only feature?

Comment: @LakshminarayananK. It is standard POSIX shell behavior, though I wouldn't call it a "feature." If you think about how a shell goes about processing a command line, it does, however, in its own way, make sense.