# Why does bash need && to echo a variable on one line?

Tags: macos, bash, unix, echo

Why does  `SOMETHING=1 && echo $SOMETHING` need `&&` to return `1`
Why doesn't `SOMETHING=1 echo $SOMETHING` return `1`

Comment: Shame on whoever downvoted your question, especially without leaving constructive feedback. It's a valid question, and the order in which bash does word/parameter/variable/tilde expansion and command execution is tricky. I'm giving you a +1.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In bash, how can I define a “command scope” variable?](http://superuser.com/q/801822/150988) – see also [Is this a bash-specific method of calling a script: VARIABLE=value bash somescript?](http://superuser.com/q/791001/150988)

Comment: technically, "echo 1" returns 0, and the output is 1... that is to say, "echo" exits with status "0", and displays to stdout the arguments. The phrasing "returns 1" to me was implying "exit staus", not "outputs", and was a bit confusing at first glance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because bash does variable expansion before interpreting variable assignment statements. So, since SOMETHING was not previously defined, your command becomes…

```
SOMETHING=1 echo ''
```

…then gets executed.

Comment: Is variable expansion the same as variable substitution?

Comment: @JoelL: Correct

Answer (score 2):

export and echo at the same time

```
root@kali:~# echo ${SOMETHING=1}
1
root@kali:~# echo $SOMETHING
1
root@kali:~# unset SOMETHING
root@kali:~# echo $SOMETHING

root@kali:~# echo ${SOMETHING=1}
1
root@kali:~#
```

Another goofier example xD

```
root@kali:~# echo ${SOMETHING=1} ${PLUS=+} ${SUMTHIN=2} ${EQUALS==} && expr $SOMETHING $PLUS $SUMTHIN
1 + 2 =
3
root@kali:~#
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to evaluate the variable later (after it gets assigned).  Use, e.g.,

```
SOMETHING=1 eval 'echo $SOMETHING'
```

to prevent propagation of `SOMETHING`.